# What is this word? (Characters Identified: 招財進寶)

Tags: word, character-identification

I was cleaning my room and found this pyramid thing with what I would guess a chinese character (because I'm chinese). Tried to look it up but couldn't find anything.
[image: Chinese character]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a graphic that combined all the characters in the phrase 招財進寶 (attract wealth and obtain treasure)

It is not a single word because you have to read it as 招財進寶 /zhāo cái jìn bǎo/

Comment: Wtf in my 20 years of being a chingling I never knew that was a thing :0 (even though I took chinese school and stuff). Thanks! o/

Comment: It is a decoration item. You can see them in some stores

Comment: It's like how English alphabets were combined into a composite in making a Company Logo, like the Volkswagen logo.